# How does pointer dereferencing work in Go?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm going through the golang tutorials at http://tour.golang.org/, and was experimenting a bit with some things in [example 29](http://tour.golang.org/#29)

For your reference, the original example is copied here:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    p = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    q = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
    r = Vertex{X: 1}  // Y:0 is implicit
    s = Vertex{}      // X:0 and Y:0
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p, q, r, s)
}
```

It's pretty basic, showing how to create instances of this fancy new struct, `Vertex`.  [Example 28](http://tour.golang.org/#28), though, shows manipulating a vertex via a pointer to it, so I modified the example a bit and was surprised by the output.  Here is the modification:

```
func main() {
    t := *q
    q.X = 4
    u := *q
    fmt.Println(p, q, r, s, t, u, t == u)
}
```

And the output:

```
{1 2} &{4 2} {1 0} {0 0} {1 2} {4 2} false
```

The thing that surprised me is that `t` is not {4, 2}, which seems to mean that changing `q.X` changed the instance of the struct that `q` pointed to.  Coming from a C/C++ background, this seems like extremely strange behavior to me.

So, what's actually going on here?  Why does using `q.X = 4` to change the Vertex not propagate to `t`?

Comment: Remember: Go does not have C++ style references like `int &x`. Only good old pointers.

Comment: in case this helps to visualize this a bit better https://play.golang.org/p/9GqtFpbIHWw

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`t := *q` makes a copy of the struct pointed to by `q`.

If you want to observe changes to `q` through `t`, then stick with a pointer:

```
var (
    p = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
    q = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
    r = Vertex{X: 1}  // Y:0 is implicit
    s = Vertex{}      // X:0 and Y:0
)


func main() {
    t := q
    q.X = 4
    u := *q
    fmt.Println(p, q, r, s, t, u, *t == u)
}
```

This produces the output you were probably looking for.

```
{1 2} &{4 2} {1 0} {0 0} &{4 2} {4 2} true
```

I'm not sure what seems extremely strange to you.  C and C++ behave the same way.  Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vertex& v)
{
    out << "{ " << v.x << ", " << v.y << " }"; 
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Vertex v = Vertex{1, 2};
    Vertex* q = &v;
    Vertex t = *q;
    q->x = 4;
    std::cout << "*q: " << *q << "\n";
    std::cout << " t: " << t << "\n";
}
```

The output of this C++ code shows the same behavior:

```
*q: { 4, 2 }  
t: { 1, 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  C++ might do this, but C definitely doesn't, unless you explicitly copy the instance.

Comment: To clarify -- it sounds like "`t := *q` makes a copy of the struct pointed to by `q`" is the answer I was looking for.  The C++ code you've provided doesn't compile as-is, and when I try to use `new Vertex`, `g++` still gives me some errors, so unless this is edited, it shouldn't be treated as a reasonable comparison example.

Comment: I'm using some C++11 syntax for initializing the struct, so you have to enable C++11 mode to compile it (usually `-std=c++11` does the trick).  See here for an example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a304f24025b4d9d

Comment: So is this not surprising because we see the same behavior in C++? Python and JS don't do this, and I guess C doesn't either.

Comment: @yangmillstheory Python and JS don't do this because Python and JS don't have pointers.  Go, C, and C++ all have pointers and all behave in this way.  When you assign the result of dereferencing a pointer to a new variable, that variable gets a copy of the value that its pointed to.