# How do you access this Go struct?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make sense of this Go struct:

```
type ListClustersOutput struct {
    _ struct{} `type:"structure"`

    // A list of all of the clusters for your account in the specified Region.
    Clusters []*string `locationName:"clusters" type:"list"`

    // The nextToken value to include in a future ListClusters request. When the
    // results of a ListClusters request exceed maxResults, you can use this value
    // to retrieve the next page of results. This value is null when there are no
    // more results to return.
    NextToken *string `locationName:"nextToken" type:"string"`
}
```

Looking at the docs: https://golangdocs.com/structs-in-golang#defining-a-struct-in-go

it gives an example:

```
type Fruit struct {
    name string
}
```

which seems very different.

In the more complex code, I assume this `` Clusters []*string `locationName:"clusters" type:"list"` `` is equivalent to `name string` but struggling to unpack it.

- I'm struggling to find much out about `type: "list"` - most of the examples seem to refer to slices. Why are they using a `list`?
- what is a `locationName`?
- how do you access the first element of the list in that struct?

Note, for this last question, if I use `result.Clusters[0]` (where `result` is of this struct type) I get a pointer. E.g.

```
    fmt.Println("Result: ", result.Clusters[0])
    Result:  0xc000372260
```

How do I dereference it?

Looking at this:

[How does pointer dereferencing work in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084401/how-does-pointer-dereferencing-work-in-go)

it seems you need an asterisk or an ampersand. Not clear which one you use or whether you tack it on the beginning or the end.

Comment: Clusters is an array of pointers to string.
You can access it using * before it (I think it's pretty much like C/C++)

Comment: Instead of reading "golangdocs" you might be better served by the official [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Answer (score 0):

You are struggling with struct tags.
In your code:

```
Clusters []*string `locationName:"clusters" type:"list"`
```

The Clusters field has a type (`[]*string`) and the rest of the declaration are 2 struct tags that you should take the value(s) of tags using [struct tag.](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

Answer (score -4):

Here's how you access it:

```
fmt.Println("Result: ", *result.Clusters[0])
```